# How to add a click event to a item renderer button in a datagrid to delete the current row?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Hi i have a data grid with customer names in the i used an inline `ItemRenderer` to add a delete button now i want to add a click event to this button how can i do this? I added an `addEventListner` method in `initApp()` listening for a click it worked, But i want to use the click event from the button please help.

```
private function delItem(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(event.target.label == "Delete User")
            {
                myArrayCollection.removeItemAt(myGrid.selectedIndex);
            }
        }
private function initApp():void
        {
            delButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,delItem);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for all your help I'm a beginner so took me some time to figure it out and here is how i solved it 
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical">
    <mx:Script>
         <![CDATA[
             import mx.controls.Alert;
             import mx.controls.Button;
             import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
             import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
             import mx.controls.DataGrid;
             [Bindable]
            private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection
             ([
                 {serial:1,name:"maniteja"},
                {serial:2,name:"laxmi"},
                {serial:3,name:"bose"}
             ]);
             public function gimmePop():void
             {
                 dp.removeItemAt(dataGrid.selectedIndex);
             }
         ]]>
     </mx:Script>

     <mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{dp}" rowCount="{dp.length}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="serial" headerText="Serial:"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name:"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="deleteButton">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:Button label="Delete User" click="outerDocument.gimmePop()"/>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:Application>`

Comment: i didnt know earlier that we could access the function out side the data grig using `outerDocument.theFunction()`

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" left="5" right="5" top="5" bottom="5">
    <s:ArrayCollection>
        <s:DataItem key="1000" name="Abrasive" price="100.11" call="false"/>
        <s:DataItem key="1001" name="Brush" price="110.01" call="true"/>
        <s:DataItem key="1002" name="Clamp" price="120.02" call="false"/>
        <s:DataItem key="1003" name="Drill" price="130.03" call="true"/>
        <s:DataItem key="1004" name="Epoxy" price="140.04" call="false"/>
        <s:DataItem key="1005" name="File" price="150.05" call="true"/>
        <s:DataItem key="1006" name="Gouge" price="160.06" call="false"/>
        <s:DataItem key="1007" name="Hook" price="170.07" call="true"/>
        <s:DataItem key="1008" name="Ink" price="180.08" call="false"/>
        <s:DataItem key="1009" name="Jack" price="190.09" call="true"/>
    </s:ArrayCollection>

    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="key"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="name"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="price"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="call"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>

    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:GridItemRenderer>
                <fx:Script><![CDATA[
                    import mx.controls.Alert;

                    private function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                        Alert.show("Click on button: " + data[column.dataField]);
                    }
                    ]]></fx:Script>

                <s:Button label="{data[column.dataField]}" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
            </s:GridItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Good practice is to define itemRenderer in separate file. Example:

```
<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" left="5" right="5" top="5" bottom="5" itemRenderer="MyItemRenderer">...</s:DataGrid>
```

MyItemRenderer.mxml file located in src directory

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.Alert;

    private function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        Alert.show("Click on button: " + data[column.dataField]);
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>

<s:Button label="{data[column.dataField]}" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/></s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Adding a script tag inside my item renderer tag is giving me a parse error im pretty new at this and im using flex 3

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553964/flex-3-and-itemrenderers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553964/flex-3-and-itemrenderers) it must help you

Comment: Give me your code and explain what exactly not working

Comment: `<mx:DataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{dp}">
    <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Serial No:" dataField="serial"/
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name:" dataField="name"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn>
    <mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
    <mx:Button label="Delete User" click="delItem(event)"/>
    </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid> `
this is my code im notable to execute the `delItem()` function on the button click. I was able to do it with the `addEventListner` method but i want to do this on click

Answer (score 1):

I hope it help you

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{dp}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Serial No:" dataField="serial"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name:" dataField="name"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:Box>
                        <mx:Script><![CDATA[
                            import mx.controls.Alert;

                            private function delItem(event:MouseEvent):void {
                                Alert.show("Click");
                            }
                        ]]></mx:Script>
                        <mx:Button label="Delete User"
                                   click="delItem(event)"/>
                    </mx:Box>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```